# Error de php en visual studio code

Tags: php

Hola les quiero pedir ayuda ya que cuando habro visual studio code y creo un archivo de php me sale "no se puede validar porque no hay ningun ejecutable php establecido" yo uso WAMP server y creo que no tiene una ruta para php, les agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Tienes que establecer la ubicación de `php.exe`, el IDE te va a dar instrucciones de cómo ponerlo

Answer (score 0):

En las preferencias de VSCode (settings.json) debes establecer la ruta dónde se encuentra tu PHP instalado.

En mi caso uso laragon y la ruta es:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\laragon\\bin\\php\\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\\php.exe",
"php.executablePath": "C:\\laragon\\bin\\php\\php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64\\php.exe",
```

En XAMPP la ruta es:
`"C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"`, me imagino que la ruta para WAMP será similar.

Comment: Wamp no tiene una ruta directa para el php.exe

Comment: Revisa el directorio de instalación de wamp, si que tiene que tener una ruta dónde se encuentre instalado el PHP, si no has modificado el directorio de instalación debería estar en c:\wamp...Prueba haciendo una búsqueda del archivo php.exe con el buscador de archivos de windows y seguro que aparece... otra cosa sería que no hubieses instalado php